# Using carriage return line feed in SQL Loader Command Line

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to use SQL Loader in a shell script so I am using command line parameters. I create the control file on the fly and later delete it inside the script after loading. My problem is that my data file has carriage returns and a lot of the records are discarded to .bad. I understand I would need to use "str '\n'" after the INFILE is specified. But how do I do that with command line?

Below is a sample of my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
   LDRFILE=$LOCAL_HOME/data/rmse_loc.ctl
   echo "LOAD DATA " > $LDRFILE
   echo "TRUNCATE "    >> $LDRFILE
   echo "INTO TABLE "R2SCHD.RDF_LOC_HIER"" >> $LDRFILE
   echo "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "("  >> $LDRFILE
   echo "LOC, " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "LOC_NAME, " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "DISTRICT, "  >> $LDRFILE
   echo "DISTRICT_NAME, " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "DEFAULT_WH, " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "DEFUALT_WH_NAME, " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "LOC_TYPE, " >> $LDRFILE
   echo "LOC_TYPE_NAME " >> $LDRFILE
   echo ")"  >> $LDRFILE
   sqlldr userid=$CONNECT control=$LDRFILE log=$LOCAL_HOME/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.$INPUT_FILE.$RUN_DATE.log bad=$LOCAL_HOME/error/$PROGRAM_NAME.$INPUT_FILE.$RUN_DATE.bad data=$LOCAL_HOME/data/$INPUT_FILE
```

Below is a sample of the first 5 rows of the data file all line ends in CR/LF:

```
34,"34 CARLISLE 67TH ST",3740,"CARLISLE NORTH",6620363,"DDDC REPLENISHMENT",S,"Store"^M
240,"240 FELTWELL SHOP",7614,"UK EAST",2220671,"GDC REPLENISHMENT",S,"Store"^M
5504,"5504 AM CLASS SIX",3720,"SAM S TEXAS",6620363,"DDDC REPLENISHMENT",S,"Store"^M
5827,"5827 JAC CLASS 6",632,"JACKSON/SHAW",9820580,"DDDC REPLENISHMENT",S,"Store"^M
100081,"100081 EGLIN MCS",944,"EGLIN AFB",6620363,"DDDC REPLENISHMENT",S,"Store"^M
```

Comment: The data file has a source and destination within UNIX, it is just when I view it on Windows with Notepad++ do I see CR LF at the end of every line when I choose to show EOL symbols.

Comment: What are the actual rejection reasons in the log? That data loads OK from Linux, into a made-up table.

Comment: ahh..I was looking into my own log file which provided less information...I see what the issue is. I am going to answer my own question with the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with CR/LF but with one of the value of the columns being too large :(. Amateur mistake, I am new to SQL Loader and was looking at my own created log instead of the actual SQL Log:

```
Record 98: Rejected - Error on table R2SCHD.RDF_LOC_HIER, column LOC_NAME.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "R2SCHD"."RDF_LOC_HIER"."LOC_NAME" (actual: 26, maximum: 25)
```